# Where can i find Burst mode on my Nikon D3300?

Tags: nikon-d3300, burst-mode

I have purchased a Nikon D3300 and cannot find Burst mode on it, could someone please tell me where to find it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Burst in the index of your D3300 camera manual.

It is page 68 in the D3300 Reference manual.

Reference manual is the much larger complete manual (as opposed to skimpy shipped version on D3xxx and D5xxx models).  It is free from Nikon at
http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/21/D3300.html